# Laravel function without return

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In class `Player` I have method:

```
public function removeFromLineupPrepare()
{
    if (isset($this->team->lineupPrepare) &&$this->lineupPreparePosition) {
        $this->team->lineupPrepare->update([
            $this->lineupPreparePosition => NULL
        ]);
    }
}
```

And when I use the above method like this:

```
if ($player->team && $request->team_id != $player->team_id) {
        $player->removeFromLineupPrepare;
}
```

I got an error:

`Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeFromLineupPrepare` is a method, but you are accessing it like a property.  Try:

```
$player->removeFromLineupPrepare();
```